# Example of a function that grows and then vanishes at infinity

Tags: functions

I am writing a simple python program to demonstrate Time Shifting a function.

I would like something like this:

[image]

Can you help me define or describe a simple function that increases rapidly and then goes to zero that I can then time-shift for my demo?

Comment: Take a look at my *gamma pulse* described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4390357/how-to-write-equations-to-shape-a-polynomial-function-only-in-the-upper-right-qu/4390499#4390499.

Comment: $x(t)=f(\frac{t-T_1+|t-T_1|}{2})$, where $f(t)$ is function for pulse.

Comment: $f(t)$ can be various, for example $f(t)=\sqrt{1-\frac{(t-1)^2}{(t+1)^2}}$